# C# NetCore_RestAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a project reference as the error says.

You should add a reference with the following steps:

1. Right click you project.
2. Then `Manage NuGet Packages...`

[image]

3. Search for `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`
4. install

[image]